# Data cleaning - Cannot get FindReplace function to work as intended

Tags: r, find-replace

I have a large dataframe with a column that has thousands of different location (city) names, and I need to simplify/clean it.

After fighting quite a lot and trying to do it with regex and loop, I found the DataCombine package and the FindReplace that is meant to do what I want but I can't manage to make it work.

So I have:

```
   UserId          Location
1   USR_1             Paris
2   USR_2            London
3   USR_3           Londres
4   USR_4           Neuilly
5   USR_5            Berlin
6   USR_6    London Chelsea
7   USR_7 Berlin Schoenfeld
8   USR_8          Paris-20
9   USR_9           Neuilly
10 USR_10     Friedrischain
```

The cleaning is just a replace, e.g. "London Chelsea" should be "London", "Brooklyn" should be "New York City", "Paris 20e" and "Paris-14" should be "Paris". To go further, I would like everything that has the pattern "Paris" to be replaced by "Paris" (sort of LIKE "Paris%" in SQL).

```
# Data for testing
library(DataCombine)
user_test <- data_frame(x <- paste("USR", as.character(1:10), sep = "_"), y <- c("Paris", "London", "Londres", "Neuilly", " Berlin", "London Chelsea", "Berlin Schoenfeld", "Paris-20", "Neuilly", "Friedrischain"))
colnames(user_test) <- c("UserId","Location")
user_test <- as.data.frame(user_test) ### Not sure why I have to put it there but otherwise it doesn't have the dataframe class
should_be <- data_frame(c("Paris", "London", "Berlin", "Neuilly", "Friedr"), c("Paris", "London", "Berlin", "Paris", "Berlin"))
colnames(should_be) <- c("is","should_be")

# Calling the function
FindReplace(data = user_test, Var = "Location", replaceData = should_be, from = "is", to = "should_be", exact = FALSE, vector = FALSE)
```

And the function returns this:

```
   UserId          Location
1   USR_1             Paris
2   USR_2            London
3   USR_3           Londres
4   USR_4             Paris
5   USR_5            Berlin
6   USR_6    London Chelsea
7   USR_7 Berlin Schoenfeld
8   USR_8          Paris-20
9   USR_9             Paris
10 USR_10     Berlinischain
```

Partially cleaned (strings have been replaced) but not the whole entries.

Any ideas on how I could do? Loop with grep? Match? Or do I really have to build a cleaning dataframe with absolutely all the desired entries.

Comment: Shouldn't the argument `replaceData` be `should_be` instead of `cleaner`?

Comment: Thanks aichao you are right, this change makes the function work as intended. But it doesn't clean the entries that have the pattern, for example in "Paris-20" it doesn't replace it with "Paris".

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. I've actually never used `DataCombine::FindReplace`.

Comment: did you have data-table which you have to replace.  i mean you have two table one is original table and other tables have values which you want to replace. If you have this i will help you in this task because i already done it.

Comment: i suggest you make one datafram which hold all the value which you want to replace. ex.  "Brooklyn"  "New York City"

Comment: I have one dataframe which holds the city names, and another dataframe that holds what should be replaced and by what it should be replaced yes.

Comment: @JeanD oh thats great. It means your problem is solved??

Comment: @sahildesai yes it is at least partially resolved. I didn't manage to get the regex part working but i just have to make a larger and more complete cleaning dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce.

```
# Data for testing
library(tidyverse)

left_join(user_test, should_be, by = c("Location"="is")) %>% 
  mutate(final = coalesce(should_be, Location))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    UserId Location          should_be final            
#>    <chr>  <chr>             <chr>     <chr>            
#>  1 USR_1  Paris             Paris     Paris            
#>  2 USR_2  London            London    London           
#>  3 USR_3  Londres           <NA>      Londres          
#>  4 USR_4  Neuilly           Paris     Paris            
#>  5 USR_5  " Berlin"         <NA>      " Berlin"        
#>  6 USR_6  London Chelsea    <NA>      London Chelsea   
#>  7 USR_7  Berlin Schoenfeld <NA>      Berlin Schoenfeld
#>  8 USR_8  Paris-20          <NA>      Paris-20         
#>  9 USR_9  Neuilly           Paris     Paris            
#> 10 USR_10 Friedrischain     <NA>      Friedrischain
Created on 2018-03-03 by the reprex package (v0.2.0).
```